# Timeline Mission loading delay

Tags: dji-sdk

Using the sample code that DJI provides (Android version), it appears as if the mission isn't loaded until after takeoff. The drone will lift off the ground about 5ft, and hover for anywhere from 5-30 seconds. After that delay the timeline mission will resume.

The official DJI software does not have that delay, and it shows that the mission is loaded before the drone even takes off. What is the process for having the drone takeoff and immediately starting the mission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself using the example in the WaypointMissionOperatorView class.

I'm not sure why there's two different ways of loading missions, but using the WaypointMissionOperator class you can load the mission before takeoff.